# Detecting file that isn't there

Tags: c, filesystems

So this is one of the first programs I've ever used some self created error checks however for some reason when I compile this and run it using:

```
./file test1.txt test2.txt 10
```

I get absolutely an error suggesting that the output file exists and I've checked the file and it doesn't even when I change the name of the output file (second argument) I get nothing. Anyone who can help? I've been racking my brain for ages now. This is a UNIX homework assignment I'm compiling and running in Gentoo. I have it running in a VB and have a linked folder between my windows and linux OS's.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFT 25

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int count;
  int readin;
  int writeout;

  printf ("This program was called  \"%s\".\n",argv[0]);

  if (argc > 1)
    {
      for (count = 1; count < argc; count++)
    {
      printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", count, argv[count]);
    }
    }
  else
    {
      perror("The command had no arguments.\n");
      exit(-1);

    }
    // check correct number of arguments parsed //


    if  (argc == 4)
    {
        printf("There are the correct number of arguments(4)\n");

        }
        else
        {
            perror("Not enough arguments! please try again \n");
            exit(-1);
            }
    //Check original file is there//

    int openFD = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
    if (openFD <0)
    {
        perror("Error unable to read file \n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    //Check existence of output file, if it doesn't exist create it//

    int CheckFile = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
    if (CheckFile < 0)
    {
        perror("Error output file already exists \n");
        exit(-1);
        }
     else
     {
     int CheckFile = open(argv[2], O_CREAT);
     printf("The file has successfully been created \n");
     }

    //Create buffer

    int bufsize = atoi(argv[3]);
    char *calbuf;
    calbuf = calloc(bufsize, sizeof(char));

    //Read text from original file and print to output//

    readin = read(openFD, calbuf, BUFFT);
    if (readin < 0){
        perror("File read error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    writeout = write(openFD,bufsize,readin);
    if (writeout <0){
        perror("File write error");
        exit(-1);
    }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error you get?

Comment: You should not use `perror` for your own error messages, as that function uses `errno` to print a message and `errno` is only valid if a system function have failed (or you set it yourself). You use it correctly after `open`, `read` and `write`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **open** call for **HANDLE CheckFile** is printing **Error File Exists**. This is your problem. You are printing out the wrong statement when **Output File Is Not Found** and moreover you are **exiting** which prevents the code to create any.

```
int CheckFile = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
if (CheckFile < 0)
{
    //Means the file doesn't exist
    int CheckFile = open(argv[2], O_CREAT);
    // Check for errors  here
}
```

And why are you trying to do this::

```
writeout = write(openFD,bufsize,readin);
```

when your **HANDLE TO OUTPUT FILE IS CheckFile**

Comment: Ah I see, the problem. I'm not meeting my brief here either, I'm meant to stop the program if the file DOES exist. I need to implement some code to do that now  I have corrected the problem. It is creating the file although I'm getting File Write Error: Bad Address now.

Comment: if CheckFile does not returns -1, exit the code else create the output file :-)

Comment: And yeah, do open the output file with permissions and correct accesses:: http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/languages/c/programming-bbrown/c_075.htm

Comment: You can always mark as "Accepted" if the solution worked for you ;-)

Comment: Hi Abhineet, your assistance has been great, unfortunately my reputation is not 15 yet! Maybe if I can contribute enough quality answers tonight I will be able to tick your box!

Answer (score 1):

```
    int CheckFile = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
    if (CheckFile < 0)
    {
        perror("Error output file already exists \n");
```

A negative return from `open` means that the file could not be opened, most likely because it does not exist ... it does not mean that the file already exists. Failing to open the input file certainly does not mean that the output file already exists. Please check your code more carefully for obvious errors, e.g.,

```
int CheckFile = open(argv[2], O_CREAT);
printf("The file has successfully been created \n");
```

Here you don't check the return code.

Comment: Ok so I've changed to a read and write mode however, I still recieve the error. As pointed out, the <0 or >0 does not necessarily mean the definite failure or success or something however I'm working off the specification and some sample code and this seems to be accepted at this level. I still have no avail with the read/write function.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this fragment of your code:

```
int CheckFile = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
if (CheckFile < 0)
{
    perror("Error output file already exists \n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

You are saying trying to open a file in READ ONLY MODE.  From what I read in your question, it's not an error if the file doesn't exist, but in the code you are validating the opposite, if the file doesn't exists, throw an error (in fact your message error is incorrect here).

Double check your logic and you will find your solution.